# two drop-down side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-server, dropdown

I want to show two drop-downs for Day and Month in SharePoint OOTB form in one row (side by side).

Comment: Not sure if ironic or not...

Answer (score 1):

You will need the following:

1. 2 form `<select>` elements.  One for the **month** and one for the **day**
2. You are going to need an algorithm to determine if the current year is a leap year.  Different calendars have [different ways of determining Leap Year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).   Im assuming Gregorian here.
3. Define a `changeDays` function and assign it to the `onChange` event handler of the **month**.  It will set the days `<options>` elements in the **day** `<select>` accordingly:

   - for Jan, Mar, May, July, Aug, Oct and Dec give it 31 days
   - for Apr, June, Sept, Nov give it 30 days
   - for Feb give it 28 days, unless leap year, then give it 29 days.
4. For Javascript/Jquery used on SharePoint 2010 wiki pages, one best practice is to develop the Javascript in a file and save it in a Document Library (as a .js file).  Then reference this file from a Content Data Web Part on the target wiki page.

Hope this helps...

Comment: hi I wanted to show two fields (drop-downs) side by side for Day and Month